# Orchestra.Shell.MahApps -> Orchestra.Windows.MetroDataWindow -> ValidateData bug?

Tags: catel, orchestra

In MetroDataWindow (Orchestra.Shell.MahApps v5.0.1)

```
protected virtual bool ValidateData()
{
    var vm = _logic.ViewModel;
    if (vm == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    vm.Validate();

    return vm.ValidationContext.HasErrors;
}
```

Does the last line reflect intended behavior?

`return vm.ValidationContext.HasErrors;`

I reached this while looking into why the OK button is disabled in the `MetroDataWindow`

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, but I think it's better to report bugs in the official [issue tracker](https://github.com/wildgums/orchestra).

Comment: FYI: this is fixed for Orchestra 5.1